# Right-Hand Rule and Reactance

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conventions

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.03420) by Guo et al., it is claimed on p. 4 that for a coil in a magnetic field, the induced current in the coil can follow either a right-hand or a left-hand rule, depending on the reactance. I've only ever heard of a right-hand rule, hence my question: how can the reactance of the coil be manipulated such that the induced current in the coil induces a magnetic field that *increases*, rather than opposes, the source field? A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it perhaps just a question of winding?

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because it is the capacitance that is decisive here, if I've understood their construction correctly.